# Convertir String en fecha Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, date

Buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente: estoy recibiendo un string en este formato

```
"fecha"= "02/09/1988"
```

entonces necesito convertirlo a un formato de fecha por lo que creo una variable que me almacena esta conversion:

```
  this.fechanaci= new Date(fecha);
```

pero al mostrar el resulatdo de esta conversion me muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
Tue Feb 09 1988 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)
```

osea me muestra 9 de Febrero de 1988 en vez de 2 de Septiembre de 1988.

No se cuál sería mi problema, he estado buscando pero no encuentro solución, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Excactamente, ¿cuál es el formato de fecha que esperas como salida?

Comment: si recibo "02/09/1988" me tiene que retornar 2 se septiembre de 1988 pero me retorna 9 de Febrero de 1988

Comment: Amigo, tan solo invierte los números del mes por los del día, y después haces la conversión a date

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo que uses la librería de javascript moment (https://momentjs.com/)

Con esa librería, basta con hacer

```
const df = moment(fecha,"DD/MM/YYYY");
```

(El segundo parámetro es el formato desde donde querés crear tu instancia de moment).

En tu caso particular:

```
this.fechanaci= moment(fecha,"DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Luego, si lo querés como "Date", podés hacer:

```
df.toDate();
```

O en tu caso:

```
this.fechanaci = moment(fecha,"DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();
```

Acá va mi fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/zhokqrjp/1/

Answer (score 0):

No se si te vale la función *parse()* del paquete **date-fns**, ahí especificas el formato en el que te entra la cadena, yo la utilizo bastante. date-fns es bastante mas ligero que moment, que tambien te valdria.

```
    // Parse 11 February 2014 from middle-endian format:
    var result = parse(
      '02/11/2014',
      'MM/DD/YYYY',
      new Date()
    )
    //=> Tue Feb 11 2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Sucede porque Date no acepta el formato con barras '/', podrias reemplazarlas con espacios y entonces si funcionaria

```js
const fecha = 02/09/1988

new Date(fecha) // No funciona

const newFecha = '02/09/1988'.replace('/', ' ') // Importante reemplazarlo por un espacio

new Date(newFecha) // Funciona
```